# Angular 8 - Conditional Routes Definitions

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

There is a need of loading the same component for two different routes.

1. (OLDER APP) The first route (landing) belongs to the hybrid application where the Angular app or component is embedded (by placing a component selector) in some CMS application.
2. (NEW CONVERSION) Another route (app/sub/landing) would load the same component but the route is different

**Explanation**
I introduce a sessionStorage variable to check if the loaded app is Hybrid or not by adding below code to the CMS app.

```
let isHybridRouteCheck = !!sessionStorage.getItem('isHybrid');
```

So if the component is loading through/in CMS application then it would display `isHybrid: true`.

And in case of pure Angular application, it would not be getting `isHybrid` so the value will be `false` (instead of null due to `!!`)

**Defining Routes**

*Hybrid Routes*

```
const HYBRID_Routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent }
...
];
```

*Angular Routes*

```
const PURENG_Routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent/org/companyname',
    redirectTo: 'parent/org/companyname/landing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'parent/org/companyname/landing',
    component: LandingComponent
  }
]
```

*App Module TS*

**Is it possible to pass routes to `RouterModule` as below code?**

For me, the below code is throwing an error of *no matching routes* in case of the `false` value for `isFwbHybridRouteCheck`. It would have considered `PURENG_Routes`. Isn't it?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(isHybridRouteCheck ? HYBRID_Routes: PURENG_Routes, { useHash: true })
    ]
});
```

Comment: I think that should work

Comment: @GuerricP, yes that is what I thought too. But unfortunately didn't :(. Do you have any solution around?

Comment: I'm wondering one thing though. Maybe the modules declarations are being evaluated at compile time (not at run time). If so, your solution won't work

Comment: Route Guard can be an option here?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple :) When you get value from localStorage it is a string value, so when you trying convert it into boolean value equals to true **always**. `Boolean('true') === true, Boolean('false') === true` also. Try to:
`const isHybrid = localStorage.getItem('isHybrid') === 'true'`;

Comment: Okay @Yan, Let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: @KushalJ. Okay, notify me if that works please, thanks.

Comment: this didn't work.

Comment: @KushalJ. Then you can use a guards as solution

Comment: the issue is to register 2 different sets of routes based on a boolean condition. How the guards would be helpful here?

Comment: @KushalJ. anyway your routes configs will include in the bundle, so you can restrict access by guard